# Split string at given positions

Tags: raku

How do i nicely/idiomatically split a string at a list of positions?

What I have:

```
.say for split-at( "0019ABX26002", (3, 4, 8) ); 

sub split-at( $s, @positions )
{
  my $done = 0;

  gather 
  {
    for @positions -> $p
    {
      take $s.substr($done, $p - $done );
      $done = $p;
    }
    take $s.substr( $done, * );
  }
}
```

which is reasonable. I am puzzled by the lack of language support for this though. If "split on" is a thing, why isn't "split at" too? I think this should be a core operation. I should be able to write

```
.say for "0019ABX26002".split( :at(3, 4, 8) );
```

Or maybe I am overlooking something?

Edit: A little Benchmark of what we have so far

```
O------------O---------O------------O--------O-------O-------O
|            | Rate    | array-push | holli  | raiph | simon |
O============O=========O============O========O=======O=======O
| array-push | 15907/s | --         | -59%   | -100% | -91%  |
| holli      | 9858/s  | 142%       | --     | -100% | -79%  |
| raiph      | 72.8/s  | 50185%     | 20720% | --    | 4335% |
| simon      | 2901/s  | 1034%      | 369%   | -98%  | --    |
O------------O---------O------------O--------O-------O-------O
```

Code:

```
use Bench;

my $s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddefggggggggggggggggggg";
my @p = 29, 65, 69, 105, 106, 107;

Bench.new.cmpthese(1000, {
  holli  => sub { my @ = holli($s, @p); },
  simon => sub { my @ = simon($s, @p); },
  raiph => sub { my @ = raiph($s, @p); },
  array-push => sub { my @ = array-push($s, @p); },
});

#say user($s, @p);


sub simon($str, *@idxs ) {
    my @rotors = @idxs.map( { state $l = 0; my $o = $_ - $l; $l = $_; $o } );
    $str.comb("").rotor( |@rotors,* ).map(*.join(""));
}

sub raiph($s, @p) {
    $s.split( / <?{$/.pos == any(@p)}> / )
}

sub holli( $s, @positions )
{
  my $done = 0;

  gather
  {
    for @positions -> $p
    {
      take $s.substr($done, $p - $done );
      $done = $p;
    }
    take $s.substr( $done, * );
  }
}

sub array-push( $s, @positions )
{
  my $done = 0;
  my @result;

  for @positions -> $p
  {
    @result.push: $s.substr($done, $p - $done );
    $done = $p;
  }
  @result.push: $s.substr( $done, * );

  @result;
}
```

Comment: So for this you're expecting : `("001", "9", "ABX2", "6002")` ?

Comment: In this case, that would be the output yes.

Comment: If you're looking for raw speed, making an explicit return array is a fair bit faster: I get ~15k with gather/take, vs nearly 19k with Array/push, but that's assuming that each item is ultimately needed.

Comment: Oh wow, i didnt expect that. I measure a near 100% speed difference between my initial code and the eqiv. code with an explicit array and pushes. Any idea why gather is so much slower?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I was wrong about gather and comb etc being lazy. But not sure. I'm just going to delete my prior message.

Comment: I didn't realise we'd be benchmarked ;)

Comment: I tried a different thing. It was slightly slower. But I feel it's nicer.

Comment: In light of this question, I've added a module: [String::Fields](https://modules.raku.org/dist/String::Fields:cpan:ELIZABETH).  It's interface is slightly different, but I think it is also more flexible and more useful in other situations.

Answer (score 10):

Personally I'd split it into a list, use `rotor` to divide the list up and join the result :

```
"0019ABX26002".comb().rotor(3,1,4,*).map(*.join)
```

If you want a split at function (using the indexes given) :

```
sub split-at( $str, *@idxs ) { 
    my @rotors = @idxs.map( { state $l = 0; my $o = $_ - $l; $l = $_; $o } );
    $str.comb("").rotor( |@rotors,* ).map(*.join("")); 
}
```

Basically if I want to do list type stuff I use a list.

I came up with another version that I really like from a functional programming sense :

```
sub split-at( $str, *@idxs ) {
    (|@idxs, $str.codes)
    ==> map( { state $s = 0;my $e = $_ - $s;my $o = [$s,$e]; $s = $_; $o } )
    ==> map( { $str.substr(|$_) } );
}
```

It works out to be slightly slower than the other one.

Comment: Eh well. We think alike, and almost at the same time :-)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of the existence of `rotor`. In this case though. You are doing a lot of work for what should be simple operation.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
.say for "0019ABX26002" .split: / <?{ $/.pos ∈ (3,4,8) }> /
```

displays:

```
001
9
ABX2
6002
```

Comment: Neat. But quite complicated.

Comment: Hi Holli. I've upvoted your comments to signal agreement with them all, including that it's slow. /// As a consolation prize for my regex approach, one can replace the original `== 3|4|8` with `∈ @pos` to improve the speed. (And some might prefer the way it reads too.)

Answer (score 3):

Because each substring does not depend on the other, hyper becomes an option.

```
method split-at(\p) {
  do hyper for (0,|p) Z (|p,self.chars) {
    self.substr: .head, .tail - .head
  }
}
```

Or in sub form:

```
sub split-at(\s, \p) {
  do hyper for (0,|p) Z (|p,s.chars) {
    s.substr: .head, .tail - .head
  }
}
```

But the overhead involved is not worth it unless the number of elements requested is extreme — in my tests it's about ten times slower than the naïve form.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I would use:

```
my method break (Str \s: *@i where .all ~~ Int) {
  gather for @i Z [\+] 0,|@i -> ($length, $start) {
    take s.substr: $start, $length
  }
}

say "abcdefghi".&break(2,3,4)   # "ab","cde","fghi"
```

The `gather`/`take` lets it be lazy if you ultimately don't need to use all of them.  The loop takes `@i` (`2,3,4` in the example) and zips it up with the cascading addition reducer `[\+]`, which would normally produce `2,5,9`, but we insert a 0 to make it `0,2,5,9` to mark the starting indexes of each one.  This lets the actual take be a simple `substr` operation.

By making it a `method` instead of a sub, you can use it just like you would (you could even name it `split` if you want, the addition of the `&` sigil means Raku won't be confused whether you want the built in or custom made one.

You could, even, add it directly to Str:

```
use MONKEY-TYPING;   # enable augment
augment class Str {
  multi method split (Str \s: *@i where .all ~~ Int) {
    gather for @i Z [\+] 0,|@i -> ($length, $start) {
      take s.substr: $start, $length
    }
  }
}

say "abcdefghi".split(2,3,4)
```

In this case, it needs to be defined as `multi method` since there are already various `split` methods.  The nice thing is since none of those are defined by only `Int` arguments, it's easy to ensure our augmented one gets used.

That said, calling it using the sigiled version in a lexical `method` is definitely the better one.

Comment: ACk, I just realized you'd prefer an `:at` named parameter, I'll update to do that.

Comment: I don't prefer it per se. I'd want it to be in the language. It's common enough. We already have half a dozen variants of `split`. Such a one would be a reasonable addition, imho.

Comment: Holli: Actually, I think it would make more sense in `comb` rather than in `split`, as comb is already designed to work on integers.  How about this? https://tio.run/##VVLJasMwFLz7KwYTgk1dZyn0kODQaw@FQo4lLbIs26LygiTThCy/7kpK3Dq66D3NPM1oUMukeO77rZbxZ87r7KtiumyywKdNlfph/CNJG3iA6lIEJxriaBqA5wD9WOxsjcsF743imjc1EXD4dIrA4jERwuKvtXZUB5p1OgEZZ/DfOqXRKQZL5LVmBZMq9q3OjVsdMFFa8roAVolRne/WI0iylhF9g5Y7zGZGLB8xXgSrC10qIHGW463gLfb7YXR8Wduoa5NgPj6vyH44t/oxLYlUA@G2SaY7WaMgumQSeSP/lR83mFxrHO9mAE2@2fC@2IRsqpXzEQ0j6z@uICYrk3zgfD4kAyPExlkcmGe3n8GEyfV4b4@anBWp2JViMz574drzFDnAJ2lKKc0Yy/O8MMuP7S8IgkW0jJ7CaBn2/S8

Comment: Also, core additions can be done, and can be proposed in https://github.com/Raku/problem-solving .  In this case, I would think a proposal to comb() might be fairly easy to get approved, although it might not make it into core until 6.f (not sure if 6.e is still open for things)

Comment: Your solution is expecting lenghts as input, not positions.

Comment: I was aware one could specify an explicit invocant in a method's signature but never imagined it could be done outside of a class. If declared as a subroutine, `break` could've also be called using the same method-like invocation (`sub break (Str \s, *@i where .all ~~ Int) { ... }; say "abcdefghi".&break(2,3,4);`).

Comment: uzlxxxx: Indeed, when subs are used as methods, the invocant is passed as the first argument (which is — coincidentally — the case whether or not an invocant is explicit in the signature).